# Displaying a name using Javascript

Tags: javascript

Am new to javascript and doing my student project. I have created a sample page where user enters the name of a place..

He can enter a maximum of 4 places.. I Just like to have a text of "Place A" on the top when user is entering 1st place and when he clicks on "Add Another Place" then "Place B" needs to be displayed to enter text and same like "Place C" and "Place D".

Here is my code

```js
var i = 0;

function isNumericKey(e) {

  if (window.event) {
    var charCode = window.event.keyCode;
  } else if (e) {
    var charCode = e.which;
  } else {
    return true;
  }

  if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
    return false;
  }

  return true;

}

function add() {

  var a = document.getElementById("ad").value;

  // alert('Please Enter Details');

  if (a != 'null' || a != '') {
    i++;

    if (i == 1) {

      //document.getElementById("input").reset();

      document.getElementById("Place1").style.display = "none";

      document.getElementById("Place2").style.display = "block";

      document.getElementById("Place2").required = true;

      document.getElementById("Place3").style.display = "none";

      document.getElementById("Place4").style.display = "none";


    } else if (i == 2) {

      //document.getElementById("input").reset();

      document.getElementById("Place1").style.display = "none";

      document.getElementById("Place2").style.display = "none";

      document.getElementById("Place3").style.display = "block";

      document.getElementById("Place3").required = true;

      document.getElementById("Place4").style.display = "none";

    } else if (i == 3) {

      //document.getElementById("input").reset();

      document.getElementById("Place1").style.display = "none";

      document.getElementById("Place2").style.display = "none";

      document.getElementById("Place3").style.display = "none";

      document.getElementById("Place4").style.display = "block";

      document.getElementById("Place4").required = true;


      document.getElementById("ad").style.display = "none";

    }
  }
}
```

```html
<form action="abc.php" method="post">

  <table width="600" ;>
    <tr>

      <td><font size=4px><label>Place</label></font>
        <br>
        <br>
      </td>

      <td>
        <input type="text" name="Place1" id="Place1" value="" style="display:block; width: 20vw;height:30px;font-size:14pt;" onkeypress="return isNumericKey(event);" required="true" />
        <br>
      </td>

      <td>
        <input type="text" name="Place2" id="Place2" value="" style="display:none; width: 20vw;height:30px;font-size:14pt;" onkeypress="return isNumericKey(event);" />
        <br>
      </td>

      <td>
        <input type="text" name="Place3" id="Place3" value="" style="display:none; width: 20vw;height:30px;font-size:14pt;" onkeypress="return isNumericKey(event);" />
        <br>
      </td>

      <td>
        <input type="text" name="Place4" id="Place4" value="" style="display:none; width: 20vw;height:30px;font-size:14pt;" onkeypress="return isNumericKey(event);" />
        <br>
      </td>

    </tr>

    <td>
      <input type="button" name="Add Another place" id="ad" value="Add Another place" onclick="add();" style="display: block; 
height: 25px; 
width: 175px; 
border-radius: 25px; 
background-color: #008CBA; 
color: #fff; 
border: #008CBA; 
cursor: pointer;" />
```

Let me know how to do this..

Comment: You do by using append function... append will help to add fields dynamically but again you need to check no of textbox set condition max = 4 so after 4 the new append should not add

Comment: I have set the no.of text box conditions to 4.. When you are entering 4th place I made the "add another place" button disabled.. Could you let me know how to use the append function dynamically and which place to use it

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_html_append_ref  check this link you will get some idea

Comment: Just control have many you have. How about this? https://jsfiddle.net/k19ot56v/

Comment: Thanks for the link and I just had a look into it.. The common data is appending over there.. I just don't know how to place different data each time.. Like Place A, Place B.....

Comment: @Litestone Thanks for the code but it is entirely different approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lots of syntax error in your HTML code, anyways beside that the solution to your problem is quite simple. I have written the following script to acquire the functionality required

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
     var i = 1;
    function add() {

        if (i == 1)
        {
            document.getElementById("Place1").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("Place2").style.display = "block";

            i++;
        }
        else if(i==2)
        {
            document.getElementById("Place2").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("Place3").style.display = "block";
            i++;
        }
        else if (i == 3) {
            document.getElementById("Place3").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("Place4").style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById("ad").style.display = "none";
        }
    }
 </script>
```

And below is my HTML code

```
<table>  
<tr>
    <td><label>Place</label></td> 
    <td><input type="text" name="Place1" id="Place1" value="" style="display:block; width: 20px;height:30px;font-size:14pt;"  placeholder="place1"/></td>  
    <td><input type="text" name="Place2" id="Place2" value="" style="display:none; width: 20px;height:30px;font-size:14pt;"  placeholder="place2" /></td> 
    <td><input type="text" name="Place3" id="Place3" value="" style="display:none; width: 20px;height:30px;font-size:14pt;"  placeholder="place3" /></td> 
    <td><input type="text" name="Place4" id="Place4" value="" style="display:none; width: 20px;height:30px;font-size:14pt;"  placeholder="place4" /></td>
</tr>  
<tr>
    <td><input type="button" name="Add Another place" id="ad" value="Add Another place" onclick="add();" /></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: you are welcome , i have removed most of the styling , you can do it on you own. thanks ..

Answer (score 0):

you need to add jquery library

```
<ol></ol>
<button id="btn2">Append list item</button>
```

try this..

$(document).ready(function(){

```
$("#btn2").click(function(){
    var count_cls = $('.munna').length;

    if(count_cls<4)
    {
     $("ol").append("<li class='munna'>Place "+count_cls+"</li>");

    }else
    {
        alert('max reached');
    }
});
```

});

i have given for li you just change it to button whatever you want

chttK :http://jsfiddle.net/6yLpw9jv/2/

Comment: <head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script></head

Comment: add jquery library in header @WhoAmI

Comment: Am unable to see the script src completely in your comment

Answer (score 0):

Something like that ???

```js
 var MAX_PLACES = 4;
 var currentEditPlace = 0;
 
 function editPlace(index)
 {
  var places = document.getElementById('places');
  var place = places.getElementsByTagName("li")[index];
  place.style.display = 'block';
  
  var span = place.getElementsByTagName("span")[0];
  var input = document.createElement('input');
  input.setAttribute("type", "text");
  input.setAttribute("value", "");
  span.appendChild(input)
  
  /** Return key => show next place */
  input.onkeydown = function(e) {
   
   /** Validation */
   if (this.value != "" && e.keyCode == 13) {
    addNewPlace();
   }
  }
  
  /** Auto focus new input */
  input.focus();
 }

    function addNewPlace() {
  if (currentEditPlace+1 < MAX_PLACES) {
   currentEditPlace++;
   editPlace(currentEditPlace);
  }
    }
 
 /** Start editing place A */
 editPlace(currentEditPlace);
```

```html
<ul id="places">
 <li style="display:none;">Place A: <span></span></li>
 <li style="display:none;">Place B: <span></span></li>
 <li style="display:none;">Place C: <span></span></li>
 <li style="display:none;">Place D: <span></span></li>
</ul>
<input type="button" value="Add new place" onclick="addNewPlace()"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the code.... But it is in another model..... I need the text box name to be as place only and there Needs to text at the top as Place A, Place B and so on...